# fetch value from url and pass it to another page in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a url of a page as

> http://localhost/projectname/admin/client/1

In the above url i have a form in which i need to fill details and save it in database. The form on this page is:

```
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'type'=>'text', 
            'name'=>'job_title', 
            'value'=>'Job Title', 
            'class'=>'form-control');
    ?>

    <?php echo form_input($data); ?>

    <?php
        $data = array(
            'type'=>'submit',
            'class'=>'btn',
            'name'=>'submit',
            'content'=>'Submit!'

        );

        echo form_button($data); 
    ?>

<?php 
echo form_close();
?>
```

On the submission of the page i wish to save it in a table but along with it i also wish to carry the id/value which is in url (in this case it is 1), and would like to carry it forward till model so that i can perform actions in database based on this id/value. Can anyone please tell how it can be done

Present code for controller

```
public function form()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('job_title','Full Name','trim|required|min_length[3]');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $regdata = array 
                    (
                        'regerrors' => validation_errors()
                    );
                $this->session->set_flashdata($regdata);    
                redirect('admin/clients');
            }   
        else
            {
                 if($this->user_model->job())
                    {

                        redirect ('admin/client');
                    }



            }

    }
```

Present code for model // In the users table i wish to add job title to that row where the id matches the value in url i.e 1

```
public function job()
    {
        $data = array(
            'job_title' => $this->input->post('job_title')
            );
        $insert_data = $this->db->insert('users', $data);
        return $insert_data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
$clientId = $this->uri->segment('3');  // will return the third parameter of url
```

Now put this **$clientId** in form in a hidden input. Now you can get the $clientId on controller function when form submits. Pass it to model or use accordingly.